# Image path in css not working properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I am trying to use images in css file in my laravel project that makes use of twitter bootstrap and Jason Lewis' Basset.

Now when I use a image in my css like

```
.div {
  background: url('asset/img/photo.jpg');
}
```

I get the path to

```
http://localhost/asset/css/less/assets/img/photo.jpg
```

However the real path should be

```
http://localhost/~Username/laravelProject/public/asset/img/photo.jpg
```

The only way to achieve this is to use this url in my css

> /../~Username/laravelProject/public/asset/img/photo.jpg

You guys would understand this is a no go if I have to move the site from local to server and have to change all the urls every time.. So Why is this not working properly? I am using this laravel starter site made by andrew13

[startersite github](https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site)

Last but not least.. this is the structure

[image]

Comment: Did you try `background: url('../../img/photo.jpg');`? The `../` lets your file know to go out of the less folder.

Comment: Yes I did.. I am getting the following url.. http://localhost/img/photo.jpg

Comment: Okay and what about `/asset/img/photo.jpg`?

Comment: The same with just asset before img :( btw.. I have to mention that I think its because the basset package compiles the css and then they go into compiled/public/assets/css/master.less

Comment: It's hard to tell but let me try and fiddle with the files.

Comment: You need to create a path relative to the **compiled CSS file's path**, not where the LESS file lives (unless they are the exact same directory). If you compile your LESS at run time using javascript, I don't know the exact solution off the top of my head. But make sure your URLs are taking into consideration the FINAL path of your compiled CSS.

Comment: Yes i know but somehow its not happening like it should be. I have tried almost every possible solution but no luck

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the path is bellow the css doc, relative file paths work by adding there files location to the beginning of the url, this means that it is looking for `(Mypath)/asset/img/photo.jpg`

(or: `public/asset/css/asset/img/photo.jpg` from what I can see)

**Without a PHP server to return dynamic url's**, sadly your only 2 options are:

- Move the CSS to the root, or at least lower then the IMG
- Use a absolute url

---

### With php you have a few options, my favorite being a "Node" structure

How this works is placing a php file in the root folder that sets a constant of its location:

```
<?php
       define('ROOTPATH', dirname(__FILE__));
?>
```

When ever you want to use this just include the file, and use `ROOTPATH`:

```
 <?php
       include 'TheFileName.php';
       echo ROOTPATH,'/public/asset/img/photo.jpg';
?>
```

On most php servers this is already set to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but on a local host with will need to use a node.

*Please note this is sudo code, some things may have to be changed*